# Azure Windows VM cannot access file share of itself by public IP address

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I made a virtual machine on Azure Virtual Machines with Windows Server 2019.

I tried to access SMB file share of the server from the same machine. But it failed.

access from: 123.123.123.123 (The same machine)
access to: 123.123.123.123 (public IP address)

```
net use \123.123.123.123\test /user:test

The specified network password is not correct.
```

I tried to access it from another PC and it succeeded. The same NSG was used between the two cases. It was not caused by the NSG or firewall settings on Windows.

access from: 1.2.3.4 (non-Azure PC)
access to: 123.123.123.123 (public IP address)

```
net use \123.123.123.123\test /user:test
```

Azure VMs only know their private address. I added the public address to the NIC. After that I was able to access the file share.

Does anybody know why I couldn't access the same machine? I guess IP address is somehow associated with the problem.

Comment: NTLM loopback prevention would be my first guess.  That said, you should never make direct changes to the network adaptor within the guest OS.

Comment: You are correct! After I set DisableLoopbackCheck to 1, I became able to access the file share with the public IP address. Thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, or why you're trying to do this, it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @RobbieCrash I agree with you. Actually it's a bad idea. But I need to operate an existing application

Comment: Exposing SMB shares to the internet is a great way to let people you don't want in your network, into your network. If you're going to do this, make sure you're logging access, make sure SMBv1 and SMBv2 are disabled, and make sure all accounts that have access to the share are sufficiently secured IE: 64character fully random passwords,  no rights within the rest of your environment, the server itself should be removed from the rest of your environment as far as it's possible to do.

Comment: I also think so.
I plan to allow access only from the same virtual network. The description in the question is just for clarification to exclude misconfigurations.
The application needs to access their own file sharing with the public address for an application-specific reason. It was made for on-premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTLM loopback protection would be my guess as you’re authenticating from the same host not via it’s hostname.